# How do I make sure services restart or start in a tvial container?

Tags: linux, shell, docker

I'm using Tvial as a mail server in conjunction with a nodemailer API, but whenever I build and go into my tvial container I see that many of the most important services haven't managed to start. I tried adding service restart lines as needed to my run shell but they don't seem to take.

```
    apt-get update
    apt-get install nano
    apt-get install -y bsd-mailx
    service postfix restart
    service rsyslog restart
    service dovecot start
    service amavis start
    /usr/local/bin/start-mailserver.sh
```

When I go into the container and do a service --status-all, this is the output

```
    # service --status-all 
     [ - ]  amavis
     [ + ]  amavis-mc
     [ + ]  amavisd-snmp-subagent
     [ - ]  clamav-daemon
     [ - ]  clamav-freshclam
     [ - ]  cron
     [ - ]  dovecot
     [ - ]  fail2ban
     [ - ]  fetchmail
     [ - ]  filebeat
     [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
     [ - ]  opendkim
     [ + ]  opendmarc
     [ - ]  postfix
     [ - ]  postgrey
     [ - ]  postsrsd
     [ - ]  procps
     [ - ]  rsyslog
     [ - ]  saslauthd
     [ - ]  spamassassin
     [ - ]  supervisor
```

Comment: Standard practice is to only run one service in a container.  If you start installing things like syslog daemons and interactive text editors and expect there to be an init system keeping things running, a virtual machine might be a better match for the environment you expect to see.

Comment: The way I understand it, docker images are effectively virtual machines? I only have nano in it for my testing and fixing stuff.

Comment: There’s some substantial differences between them; it’s better to think of a container as an isolation wrapper around a single process.

Comment: Okay, but tvial does come with most of this stuff already so I'd hope that I'm not already somehow overloading the container.